# Apply templates styles on view-models in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I'm working on a WPF application, the application contains a designer which shows a vertical ListView of different elements (shapes).

I created a View-Model for the designer, and View-Model for each shape. To bind the View of the designer to the View-Model, I used the "DataContext" property.

But my problem is that I defined all the view-styles (templates) of the shapes in one XAML file, I don't know how to bind them to their view-models !!

I found this in the internet :

```
var resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("SymbolTemplates.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
        };

Style template = resourceDictionary["SMS"] as Style;
```

So I put it in my view-Model constructors, but what have I to do with the feild "template" ??

To make things more clear:

1)Here is my designer view :

```
<Grid SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged"> 
  <ListView x:Name="ShapesViewer" BorderThickness="0" Background="YellowGreen" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildrenList}"> 
    <ListView.LayoutTransform> 
       <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Orientation}" />
    </ListView.LayoutTransform> 
  </ListView> 
</Grid>
```

"ChildrenList" contains the list of my shapes view-Models.

2) Here is my "SymbolTemplates.xaml" where I defined all my shapes styles:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:ViewModel;assembly=ViewModel">
<Style x:Key="CircleStyle"
       TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <!--Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />-->
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="70" />
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="32" />
    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Grid Height="32"
                      Width="50"
                      Background="Transparent">
                    <Grid.HorizontalAlignment>
                        <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource EvenToHorizontalAlignementMultiConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Position" />
                            <Binding Path="RenderCenter" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Grid.HorizontalAlignment>
                    <Ellipse Width="30"
                             Height="30"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             StrokeThickness="3" 
                             Fill="WhiteSmoke">
                    </Ellipse>
                     <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                                    Visibility="{Binding IsExpanded, Converter= {StaticResource VisibilityOfBool} }" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
...
```

So, I have this style defined (for a circle), I have also an object CircleVM (the view-model).

my question is : **What should I do to assign this "CircleStyle" to my "CircleVM" when adding it in the "ChildrenList" defined in my ListView (named "ShapesViewer")?**

Comment: Can you show us your view? You may be able to handle the data templating of your shapes in there

Comment: Thank you for replay, yes of course, here is my ListView:

    <Grid SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged">
            <ListView x:Name="ToolStringTree"
                  BorderThickness="0"
                  Background="YellowGreen"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ChildrenList}">
                <ListView.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Orientation}" />
                </ListView.LayoutTransform>
            </ListView>
    </Grid>

ChildrenList Contains the list of my shapes view-models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE >>>

To address the statement you made in bold:

Your `Style` is *not* 'for a circle' as you say... it is for a `ListViewItem`. You cannot set a `Style` with `TargetType="ListViewItem"` to a `UserControl`.

Instead of doing this, define a `DataTemplate` for each view that defines how you want the data in each view model to appear... for example (assuming your `Circle` class has a public `Name` property in it):

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourDataTypesNamespace:Circle}">
    <Grid Height="32" Width="50" Background="Transparent">
        <Ellipse Width="30" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="WhiteSmoke" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

UPDATE END >>>

Firstly, you can load a `DataTemplate` from your `Resources` section like this:

```
ComponentResourceKey templateKey = new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(YourViewModel), 
"YourViewModelDataTemplate");
DataTemplate dataTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.TryFindResource(templateKey);
```

Then you can connect the `DataTemplate` with a particular `ContentControl` like this:

```
contentControl.ContentTemplate = dataTemplate;
```

This assumes that you have a `ContentControl` named `contentControl`.

Alternatively, you can create a simple `DataTemplate` to connect each view with its related view model programmatically like this:

```
DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
dataTemplate.DataType = typeof(YourViewModel);
FrameworkElementFactory view = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(YourView));
dataTemplate.VisualTree = view;
```

UPDATE >>>

However, if you have a view (`UserControl`) for each of your view models, then there is a *much* easier way to connect them... add these into `App.xaml`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:CircleViewModel}">
    <Views:CircleView />
</DataTemplate>
...
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SquareViewModel}">
    <Views:SquareView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: thank you for that answer, where should I write this ? in my shapes view-models ?

The views of my shapes are just "styles" defined in an XAML file, so I think I have to load a style "a" and assign it to the view-model "a_vm" when creating it. Is that true ?